# How to subset a pandas dataframe based on a condtion of a categorical variable

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, conditional-statements, subset

**My goal**

I'm struggling with creating a subset of a dataframe based on the content of the categorical variable S11AQ1A20. In all the howtos that I came across the categorical variable contained string data but in my case it's integer values that have a specific meaning (YES = 1, NO = 0, 9 = Unknown). Therefore, I added categories to let pandas label the values properly.

Ideally, Case A and B in the sample code below would contain 5 rows after the subsetting is done. But currently, it only works if i don't label the integer values.

**What I have figured out so far**

- Case B shows that the subsetting ins't performed as expcted as soon as categories are added with the following line:

`df.S11AQ1A20 = df.S11AQ1A20.cat.rename_categories(['Yes', 'No', 'Unknown'])`

**Sample Dataset**

The sample dataset (nesarc_short.csv) used for testing can be found here: https://pastebin.com/NkTeBsDR

**Example Code:**

```
dataset_path = 'nesarc_short.csv'
df = pd.read_csv(dataset_path, low_memory=False, na_values=' ')

print('CASE A: NUMERICAL -> working\n')

df = pd.read_csv(dataset_path, low_memory=False, na_values=' ')

print("A: Rows before: " + str(len(df.S11AQ1A20))) # Outputs: 100

df = df[(df.S11AQ1A20 == 1)]

print("A: Rows after: " + str(len(df.S11AQ1A20))) # Outputs: 5


###############################################################


print('\nCASE B: CATEGORICAL -> Not working\n')

df = pd.read_csv(dataset_path, low_memory=False, dtype={ 'S11AQ1A20' : 'category' }, na_values=' ')

# If this is commented out, the subsetting works but no labels will be available
df.S11AQ1A20 = df.S11AQ1A20.cat.rename_categories(['Yes', 'No', 'Unknown'])

print("B: Rows before: " + str(len(df.S11AQ1A20))) # Outputs: 100

df = df[(df.S11AQ1A20 == 'YES') | (df.S11AQ1A20 == '1') | (df.S11AQ1A20 == 1)]

print("B: Rows after: " + str(len(df.S11AQ1A20))) # Outputs: 0
```

**Console output**

> CASE A: NUMERICAL-> working
>
> A: Rows before: 100
>
> A: Rows after: 5
>
> ---
>
> CASE B: CATEGORICAL -> Not working
>
> B: Rows before: 100
>
> B: Rows after: 0

Comment: It would be helpful if you submit a [MWE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) including some data for demonstration purposes such that your issue can be reproduced. Also note that your check `df_helper.df['S12Q2A12'] == 1` is very different from `df_helper.df['S12Q2A12'] == 'YES'` since the first one is comparing integers whereas the other one compares strings. It really depends on the data in the column which filter is to be used.

Comment: there are many many many many questions on SO about using conditionals to select rows from dataframes. it would be helpful if you looked at some of them and explained why they don't solve your problem. A MWE is crucial as well. Voting to close for now, will retract when you update the question.

Comment: alright, ill update the post and try to make the question to be more reproducable

Comment: String comparisons in python are case sensitive (`'Yes' != 'YES'`) so try `df[(df.S11AQ1A20 == 'Yes')... `

Comment: @Parfait You are totally right :) I kinda missed the forest for the trees.